# Is there a countable form for "literature"?

Tags: uncountable-nouns, literature, countable-nouns

*Literature* is an uncountable noun, so we can't say *one literature* or *two literatures*.

But is there a countable form, as there is for *information*? *One piece of information*, for instance.

Comment: 'Literature' _is_ also used as a count noun (look at the links [here](https://www.google.com/webhp?hl=all#hl=all&q=literatures) for some examples from the academic world). 'One work of literature' corresponds to 'one piece of information'.

Comment: We may need more detail to answer the question properly. What you say depends on meaning you want to convey. You can say "the literatures of China and of India". And as @Edwin says, you can say "one work of literature".

Comment: Will 'literary work' (*pl*. 'literary works') do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As comments on the original question indicate, "literatures" is indeed countable:

- "two literatures": [...of Wales](http://www.press.uchicago.edu/ucp/books/book/distributed/C/bo5533323.html), or "[media and politics](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1111/1467-856X.t01-1-00009/abstract)" as "two literatures";
- "three literatures": e.g., in [English, Latin, and Greek](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=3xpKAAAAMAAJ);
- or even, "[one, two, or three literatures](http://books.google.co.uk/books?hl=en&lr=&id=cWZCAAAAQBAJ&oi=fnd&pg=PA317&dq=%22three+literatures%22&ots=AFGlw7RRhW&sig=UEwjrA2ktCFjLn6mM3OlvhU_u20&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q&f=false)" in the history of Caribbean literature.

So it seems "literatures" can be counted after all. (Plus, as [Edwin Ashworth notes](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/144061/is-there-a-countable-form-for-literature#comment296006_144061), reference to a single uses "work (of literature)".)

Comment: Incidentally, what the OP means is the countable noun corresponding to the uncountable *literature*. The sense of 'literatures' in the above examples is like 'peoples', which is a different story.

Comment: @Kris - right - I see the point, though that isn't clear from OP's form of the question. With that nuance, your "literary work" is excellent. (IMO) (Although a "literary work" ≠ "literature", but that's the problem with the vagueness in the OP.) ;)

Comment: Yes, I shouldn't have stated that literature was uncountable. The thing is, someone asked in an exam why the right answer was "I've brought some literature about Ireland" and not "I've one literature about Ireland". And in fact "one literature about Ireland" sounded incorrect to me, but I guess she was right, you could say "I've brought one literature about Ireland" just as well, right?

Comment: @henrique-ordine - [quote]you could say "I've brought one literature about Ireland" just as well, right?[/quote] - No, actually. In this case, "...some literature..." is correct, or if specifying one, then "a work of literature" or "a literary work" in order to refer to a single item. The "problem" is that "literature" (pl.) will always refer to bodies of literature of a given category (Irish, political, etc.), not to a number of individual specimens. (Hope that makes sense!)